# Open gallery for all images

Tags: android

I am trying to open gallery for also external files but it shows only internal.

```
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

To open gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    mImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath);
    mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
}}
```

To get actual path of file:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks! But It shows only internal images not external files from sdcard

Comment: Well this code is working fine for internal as well as external image selection.

Comment: Replace intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK); with intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

And onActivityResult use the following code.

```
 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
  if (data != null) {
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
 Cursor cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);

 cursor.moveToNext();
 try {  
 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
 String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
 convertedString = convertBitmapToString.upload(picturePath);
 File file = new File(mFileTemp.getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select Image from gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    cursor.close();
                } 
else {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to show all images include from sdcad, external file.It shows just internal files